# What is the difference between "under ..." and "stipulated by ..." in legal expression?

Tags: legal-terms, definition, law-of-the-sea

I have a question about whether I should use “under” or “stipulated by” in the sentence below.

1. Responsible for navigation, cargo handling, fire and life-saving equipment, and other duties related to safe operation of ships **under** international conventions.
2. Responsible for navigation, cargo handling, fire and life-saving equipment, and other duties related to safe operation of ships **stipulated by** international conventions.

Because duties of mariners are mandatary and written into international conventions, I am wondering whether the use of these two words may cause different meanings and understanding to readers. Which word is best to reflect the meaning of "**written into**"?

In addition, can I use “**stipulated under**” to replace stipulated by? Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

To me, they are synonymous but [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) legislation often uses "*in accordance with*" as well.

By way of an example: a word search of that phrase in the [Merchant Shipping and Maritime Security Act 1997](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1997/28?timeline=false) returns 91 hits, whereas "*under an order*" and "*under regulations*" have just three each, and "*stipulated*" does not appear at all.

Comment: I agree under U.S. law. The word "under" would be preferred to "stipulated" as a matter of customary usage, but I can't think of any circumstance in which they have different meanings.